# Adding text onto a custom keyboard in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm in the midst of trying to create a custom keyboard using this guide https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-with-xamarin-forms-android-4fa3b83dad1d. The only problem I'm finding at the moment is that the way the  element works only allows for Rows and Keys to be added, but I need to add some custom text to the section just above the keyboard, that could be defined in as a bindable property in the keyboard. Like so:

```
<local:EntryWithCustomKeyboard
                x:Name="entry1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                LabelText="My text up here"
                Margin="0, 0, 0, 20"
                Keyboard="Text"
                TextColor="Black"
                Placeholder="Custom Keyboard entry..." />
```

To give this kind of result:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can rewrite the keyboard to change the layout in the .xml file.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT which xml file in the link I gave?

Comment: You can check the [special_keyboard.xml](https://gist.github.com/FabriBertani/e4c563ca34d2d1c15ee959d1532f5a8d#file-special_keyboard-xml). It defines the keyboard format.